# Is it illegal to sublet apartment to someone not on lease? Penalties?

Tags: united-states, real-estate-leasing, virginia

I have a 2 BR apartment which I have been using to sublet to tenants for several years.  I don't put them on my lease. Is this illegal, and if so, what are the penalties?

Comment: Probably depends upon what your lease says about subletting.

Comment: Depends on where you live but you didn't specify a country etc. or lease details.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea Virginia, U.S. If I recall, lease details say that any additional occupants, with occupancy > 3 months, *should* be added to the lease. I have breached this lease agreement by not doing so, but is this illegal?

Comment: Breach of this type of contract is not a legal offense. You can be evicted or sued, but the police aren't going to arrest you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A breach of a legal agreement (such as a lease agreement) is indeed illegal. This is generally handled by civil law, not criminal law. Likely, the lease agreement states that your lease can be terminated if you violate the agreement. You may also be liable for monetary damages.

You will want to read your lease agreement carefully. It will specify what happens if you violate it.